# Why can Epsilon equal the absolute value of the function divided by $2$? ($\varepsilon = \frac{|f(\text{point of interest})|} 2 > 0$)

Tags: limits, functions, continuity, epsilon-delta

I am trying to solve a tricky textbook problem that requires the use of the epsilon-delta definition of a limit. However, with my elementary understanding of how to answer these kinds of problems, the solution on the back of the book begins its solution by stating something along these lines:

*Since f(point of interest) can't be 0 [in this question's scenario], and the function is continuous on the point of interest, then you can say:*

$$\varepsilon = \frac{|f(\text{point of interest})|}{2} > 0$$

How is this possible? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought epsilon was only calculable through direct manipulation of delta. How can you make this deduction without delta, just from knowing that the function at a point of interest can't be $0$?

Any help please? Thank you.

PS: The only information given for δ is it's non-negative ($δ >0$). That is it.

Comment: At least from what you quoted in the post, $\epsilon$ is just a number; it's positive because $f(\text{point}) \not= 0$. For that matter, what is $\delta$ here? There's no reference to it in the problem.

Comment: Apologies, I'll rectify that in the question. Specifics for δ are not provided. It is just stated that there exists some δ > 0. What I paraphrased in the question was the first step to the solution.

Comment: Can you add the full problem? $\epsilon$ is just a symbol; I can say $\epsilon = 0.12345$ if I want, or $\epsilon$ is a random variable following a standard normal distribution, or $\epsilon$ is the null string, or etc. The setup for the usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit is that there exists for each $\epsilon > 0$ some $\delta = \delta(\epsilon)$ such that interesting stuff happens, but I'm not sure what the context is here.

Comment: Did you mean "requires" or would "uses" be a better word?

Comment: +1 to @anomaly, and I also think that maybe you have switched the orders - usually you fix an arbitrary $\epsilon$, and get a $\delta$ for which $|x- poi| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(poi)| < \epsilon$ where $poi$ is point of interest